# Creating a CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am calling a web service and getting all the data in a byte array. Now, I want to keep all this data in the CSV file.

When I try to write the below code, it says, file is courrupted. But even after the warning I open up, it gets saved in Excel format.

Can anyone guide me on this?

```
string delimiter = ",";
matrixserverpath  == //web service call
string filePath = @"\\test.net\excel\docs\file1.csv"; //trying to create this

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
     System.IO.File.Create(filePath).Close();
}

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
WebDownload w = new WebDownload(3600000);
UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] data = w.DownloadData(matrixserverpath + PRD);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, data[index]));
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

I want to save in a CSV file format, but it stores in Excel format.

Comment: At what line do you get this exception? Can you pls add exception details? BTW you don't need to do `w = null; objUTF8 = null;`, C# handles this fine.

Comment: What is the format of the original file? If it is Excel then you first need to save the file and write code to convert later. Try saving the file as .xls first and make sure it's the correct file.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in notepad to verify it is actually .xls(x) and not csv?

Comment: Am I reading this right - do you want to store the bytes that you get from the download as a CSV file? Does your code actually create a file? If yes, what does it look like when you open it in Notepad?